# calling function in print(""" """)

Tags: python

I want to call a function in formatted output of string using `print(""" """)` function of Python. For example:

```
print("""
something.......something...
abs(-10.5)
and then again some string......
""")
```

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is how you can do it using the new and improved string [`format`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#new-string-formatting)ting method (Python 2.6 and up):

```
print("""
something.......something...
{0}
and then again some string......
""".format(abs(-10.5)))
```

Comment: @NeilG: Yeah, if you want to give up all the clarity you gained by the new format, so it's just as confusing as the old one :)

Answer (score 4):

You should do it like this:

```
print("""
something.......something...
%s
and then again some string......
""" % abs(-10.5))
```

Instead of `%s` you can for example use `%.3f` which will give you 3 decimals precision, i.e. 10.500. See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
print "whatever you want %s and then some" %abs(x)
```

Comment: A good answer for python 2.x, but I think the questioner is assuming python 3.x